# Bubble sort ins't looping through entire array. Can someone help point out what's incorrect

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting

When i check the console it seems to only sort half of the code, I can't see why.

```
  var sorted;
    var myArray = [4, 3, 1, 10, 22, 13, 100, 25, 35, 95, 0, 1];

    function bubbleSort(arr) {

       var end = arr.length - 1;

       sorted = true;

       for (var i = 0; i < end; i++) {

           if (arr[i] < arr[i + 1]) {

             var temp = arr[i];
             arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
             arr[i + 1] = temp;
             sorted = false;
           }
        end--
       }
    }

    do {
    bubbleSort(myArray)
    } while (!sorted)
    console.log(myArray)
```

I have a feeling it may have to do with my boolean flag, but everything looks correct to me.

Comment: Why do you have `end--` there? You need to iterate over the whole array every time.

Comment: @zerkms because the OP is sorting from right to left. `arr[i+1] = arr[i]` if `arr[i] < arr[i+1]`

Comment: @mhodges so? The tail is not guaranteed to be sorted after the first iteration.

Comment: @zerkms Oh, duh. Yeah.. `i` and `end` are meeting in the middle, hence why only half the array is getting sorted.

Comment: You will want to put that `end--` in the do-while loop. And yes, that boolean flag is weird. Try to avoid global variables, and pass everything explicitly.

Comment: Technically `end--` is redundant there at all.

Comment: Since no one tries to improve the solution, here is a slightly cleaner implementation of the in-place bubble sort: https://pastebin.com/fcZMx1j9

Comment: @zerkms removing end fixed it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your algorithm shows that you're sorting right to left. You're almost right except for the fact that you shouldn't do the `end--` if you're also doing `i++`. Simply remove the `end--` and you should be on your way:

```js
var sorted;
var myArray = [4, 3, 1, 10, 22, 13, 100, 25, 35, 95, 0, 1];

function bubbleSort(arr) {
   sorted = true;

   for (var i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
       if (arr[i] < arr[i + 1]) {
         var temp = arr[i];
         arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
         arr[i + 1] = temp;
         sorted = false;
       }
   }
}

do {
    bubbleSort(myArray)
} while (!sorted)

console.log(myArray)
```